# How to trigger reactive form valueChanges subscription only on input blur and enter key in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, typescript

I'm working on a form that is supposed to update some ui parts only on input blur or enter key pressed. I'm a big fan of reactive forms and I'm trying to figure out what is the proper way. So far I haven't found too many answers for reactive forms. Most of them are focused on template driven forms. I got something like this so far:

**Form component** Dynamic form values change at runtime (No predictable filed names)

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, 
    ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core'
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"
import { DEBUG } from '../../../../config/config'
import * as Debug from 'debug'

// Interfaces
import { Foo } from '../../interfaces/foo'

// Services
import { FooService } from '../../services/foo.service'

// Debug
const debugOff = (...any) => { }, debug = Debug('app:FooCmp')

@Component({
    selector: 'foo-data-cmp',
    templateUrl: './foo.data.cmp.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    styleUrls: ['./foo.data.cmp.css']
})
export class FooDataCmp {

    private _foo: Foo[] = null
    @Input('foo')
    set foo(foo: Foo[]) {
        this._foo = foo
        DEBUG.input && debug('Input foo:', this._foo)
    }
    get foo(): Foo[] {
        return this._foo
    }

    // Forms
    public fooForm: FormGroup
    public fooForm$: Observable<any>
    private updatedFoo: any[] // Updated form values

    // Subscriptions
    private subscriptions: any[] = []

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private fooService: FooService,
    ) {
        DEBUG.constr && debug('Construct FooDataCmp')
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        DEBUG.init && debug('Initialise FooDataCmp')

        // Form
        this.initFooForm()
        this.subcribeToFormChanges()
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        DEBUG.destroy && debug('Destroy FooDataCmp')
        this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe())
    }

    private initFooForm() {
        DEBUG.cmp && debug('Initialise foo form')

        // Build the form
        this.fooForm = this.formBuilder.group(this._foo)

        // Prevent undefined error at first keystroke
        this.updatedFoo = this._foo
    }

    private subcribeToFormChanges() {
        this.fooForm$ = this.fooForm.valueChanges
        let sub = this.fooForm$.subscribe(fooForm => {
            DEBUG.cmp && debug('Form changes fooForm', fooForm)
            this.updatedFoo = fooForm
        })
        this.subscriptions.push(sub)
    }

    /**
     * <!> Important step in the data update process
     * Update state store. 
     * Other services / components are subscribed to the state store itself
     */
    public refreshAllFooRelatedData () {
        DEBUG.cmp && debug('Refresh all foo related data')
        DEBUG.cmp && debugOff('Updated foo', this.updatedFoo)
        this.fooService.refreshAllFooRelatedData(this.updatedFoo)
    }

    public refreshAllFooRelatedDataOnEnter (e: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (e.keyCode !== 13) {return}
        DEBUG.cmp && debug('Refresh all foo related data (on enter)')
        DEBUG.cmp && debugOff('Updated foo', this.updatedFoo)
        this.fooService.refreshAllFooRelatedData(this.updatedFoo)
    }

    public debugTemplate() {
        DEBUG.render && debug('Render FooDataCmp')
    }

}
```

**Form template**

```
<form [formGroup]="fooForm">
    <table class="list expiries">
            <td *ngFor="let value of foo; let i = index">
                <input type="text" [formControlName]="foo[i]" 
                    (blur)="refreshAllFooRelatedData()" 
                    (keydown)="refreshAllFooRelatedDataOnEnter($event)">
            </td>
    </table>
</form>

{{ debugTemplate() }}
```

Is this a decent solution or am I missing some trick? My question is if this is the proper way to do it. I've been expecting to find some form API options for handling this task. My approach was to build on top of the forms, but I would rather use the full form api if there is anything available for this task

Comment: *Is this a decent solution...?* Are you asking if we like what you did, or is this not working for you? If so, where exactly is the issue? Reactive forms are very well [document](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). [Forms Controls](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) are too.

Comment: My question is if this is the proper way to do it. I've been epxecting to find some form API options for handling this task. My approach was to build on top of the forms, but I would rather use the full form api if there is anything available for this task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine blur and enter event into a subject and merge it with the valuechange Observable, so that it only fires value when blur or enter. I haven't fully tested the code just an idea and I have come across similar scenario before

```js
// component
this.updateField=new Subject()

this.form.get('yourfield').valueChanges.withLatestFrom(updateField).map(res=>res[0]).subscribe()

//html
<input (blur)="updateField($event)" (keydown.enter)="updateField($event)"/>
```

Comment: That is a neat idea! I knew something could be done better. Thanks! Damn, actually I now realise I was so blind... I will update when I do the modification. Observables Ftw! :D

Answer (score 62):

if anyone in  the future find this, there is actually something built into reactive forms for this, the `updateOn` option:

```
new FormControl('', {updateOn: 'blur'});
```

this will cause valueChanges and validation and whatnot to only trigger on blur

Comment: @Jojo  OP already got an accepted answer. Combining Observables as in the accepted answer and using update on blur would be the best solution from a reactive forms perspective. Besides, the observable stream in the accepted answer doesn’t even achieve the goal.

Comment: Actually this only runs validation checks on blur while the valuechanges still gets triggered for every value change (keystroke)

Comment: This, in my opinion, is a much more elegant solution and accomplishes everything needed by the original question.

Comment: This is much better and neat solution, and solves my purpose of updating only a singe field based on blur

Answer (score 0):

````
// component
public ctrl: FormControl = new FormControl(0, {updateOn: 'blur'});

//html
<input [formControl]="ctrl" (keydown.enter)="$event.target.blur()"/>```
````